# AZURE COSMOS DB with Read and Write enabled on two regions,can we have ADF pipeline running on both?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

We are planning to have few operations of ADF pipeline jobs pointing to one primary region of Cosmos DB and other pipeline jobs pointing to another region. we have enabled read and write on both region of Cosmos DB. kindly suggest,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the preferred region setting on the source using Copy Activity or Data Flows

Comment: Thanks, could see the preferred region on connection string of Cosmos DB.
And then in ADF while manually creating the linked services trying to fill in connection string of preferred region.